# C++ Clang formatter: how to avoid rearranging/sorting include blocks at all?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang, visual-studio-code

I am using the VS Code C/C++ extension which includes the C++ Clang code formatter/beautifier.
 It is working out really well formatting my C++ code just how I want it except for one small issue.
It keeps sorting/re-arranging my include blocks at the start of the file.

I tried the `IncludeBlocks` configuration style options from [their documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) but there doesn't seem to be an option to not rearrange/sort the include blocks. It happens even by default.
 Is there a way to preserve my original order of including headers?

My current configuration inside the `settings.json` file for VS Code looks like this:

```json
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
  "-C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle"
],
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0, UseTab: Always }",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

Comment: I'd give a try to `SortIncludes: false`

Comment: @R2RT After doing that it somehow stops formatting the document at all :/

Comment: `clang-format --dump-config` will give you a configuration that you can use as starting point for you `.clang-format` file. One of the configurations shown is `SortIncludes`, as mentioned by @R2RT. You can choose the "base style" like `clang-format --style google --dump-config`. See clang-format help to see which other styles are available. I tried a few ones and in all of them `SortIncludes` was set to true.

Answer (score 2):

```
// clang-format off
#include <windows.h>
#include <digitalv.h>
#include <vfw.h>
#include <joystickapi.h>
#include <mmddk.h>
#include <mmeapi.h>
#include <mmiscapi.h>
#include <mmreg.h>
#include <msacm.h>
#include <timeapi.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
```